# How to create a vertical slider in material-ui

Tags: material-ui

All of the examples show horizontal sliders, is it possible to have a vertical slider instead?

http://www.material-ui.com/v0.14.4/#/components/slider

Comment: material-ui does not offer this. The reason for that is probably because the Google material design principles don't have any recommendations for such behavior.

Comment: Okay thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

The [Slider](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/slider) component in the current Material-UI has an `axis` prop, that accepts either `"x"` or `"y"` as its value. So for a vertical slider, you would be doing, as shown on the linked page:

```
<Slider axis="y" ... />
```

Comment: >= v4.0.0  https://mui.com/components/slider/#vertical-sliders

Answer (score 0):

You could work around this by adding...

`transform: rotate(-90deg);`

to the .mdl-slider__container class of your slider.

Comment: well it doesn't really matter which library you are using. The idea here is to have a work around since the library you are using doesn't have a vertical slider. Basically you just have to find the class for the container of your slider (or add your own class) and the apply the CSS mentioned above to it.

Comment: This doesn't rotate the mouse event handling. Will not work.